# How to play a google audio ad?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, google-publisher-tag

I have a google audio ad link say something like `https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/something` and I want to play this audio ad link in my website audio content. How can I do that ?

Note:
My website uses plain HTML, CSS, JS

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to play this audio ad link in my website audio content" ? Do you want your player to display an ad banner that is clickable ?